# stop videoplayer in fragment on pressback

Tags: android, android-videoview, onbackpressed

I have video view in my fragment and its working. And on Pause method I am calling stop player its working. But when I am pressing back, I am going to old fragment and video still playing.

> how to stop video view player on back press in fragment .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add below code,under fragment

```
getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
getView().requestFocus();
getView().setOnKeyListener( new OnKeyListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey( View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event )
        {
            if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK )
            {
               videoView.stopPlayback();
            }

        }
    } );
```

Comment: on back press in activity or fragement

Comment: but where i added in fragement i didint got fragemnt object

Comment: plese help me  fragment.getView().setOnKeyListener( new OnKeyListener() i m not geting fragemnt object

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setFocusableInTouchMode(boolean)' on a null object reference

Comment: getview i got null

Comment: in oncreateview

Comment: sorry for disturwing but if i got result i  will upvote and accept anser

Comment: please upvode for me also